# Tableview cell values change after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting the placeholders for a `cell` inside the `if(cell == nil)` condition.

Still, when I scroll my table, The placeholder values get interchanged. Please help on this.

Here is the code from `CellForRowAtIndexpath`: Please let me know where I'm mistaking..

```
static NSString *cellIdentifierCell = @"MTRegisterTableViewCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell];
        if (cell == nil)
        {


NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[MTUtility 
setXibWithName:cellIdentifierCell] owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            if(indexPath.row==6)
            {

                if (cell.txtRegister.text.length == 0) {
                    if (cell.txtRegister.placeholder.length == 0) {
                        cell.txtRegister.placeholder=[self.profileTitlesArray 
objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"Placeholder :%@ && iINDEXPATH.ROW 
:%ld",cell.txtRegister.placeholder,(long)indexPath.row);

            }
            else
            {
                if (cell.txtRegister.text.length == 0) {

                    if (cell.txtRegister.placeholder.length == 0) {
                        cell.txtRegister.placeholder=[self.profileTitlesArray 
objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        if(indexPath.row==5)
        {
            static NSString *cellIdentifierCell = @"MTRegisterDropdownCell";

            MTRegisterDropdownCell *cellDrop = [tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell];
            if (cellDrop == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib;
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[MTUtility 
setXibWithName:cellIdentifierCell] owner:self options:nil];
                cellDrop = (MTRegisterDropdownCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
                [cellDrop configureCell:nil];
            }
            self.countryCell=cellDrop;
            cellDrop.clipsToBounds=NO;

            self.tblDropdown.clipsToBounds=NO;
            [cellDrop.btnCountry addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCountryClicked:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cellDrop.btnState addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonStateClicked:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if(self.strSelectedCountry)
            {
                [cellDrop.txtCountry setText:self.strSelectedCountry];
            }
            else{
                if ([self.countriesArray containsObject:kDefaultCountry]) {
                    [cellDrop.txtCountry setText:kDefaultCountry];
                    NSInteger index = [self.countriesArray 
indexOfObject:kDefaultCountry];
                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index 
inSection:0];
                    self.tblDropdown.tag=TABLECOUNTRYTAG;
                    [self tableView:self.tblDropdown didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                }

            }
            if(self.strSelectedState)
            {
                [cellDrop.txtState setText:self.strSelectedState];
            }
            return cellDrop;
        }

        else
        {
            if (cell.txtRegister.text.length == 0) {

                NSLog(@"Placeholder :%@",cell.txtRegister.placeholder);
                if ([cell.txtRegister.placeholder isEqualToString:@"City"]) {
                    if (self.strSelectedCity) {
                        cell.txtRegister.text = self.strSelectedCity;
                    }
                    else
                        cell.txtRegister.text=[self.profileTitlesArray 
objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    NSLog(@"profileTitlesArray :%@",self.profileTitlesArray);
                    NSLog(@"indexpath.Row :%ld && cell TEXT :%@",
(long)indexPath.row,cell.txtRegister.text);
                    BaseButton *aBtn = [[BaseButton alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.txtRegister.frame.origin.x-50, 
cell.txtRegister.frame.origin.y-10, cell.txtRegister.frame.size.width+50,   
cell.txtRegister.frame.size.height+50)];
                    [aBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [cell.txtRegister addSubview:aBtn];
                    [aBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCitiesClicked:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    self.cityCelll = cell;
                    cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
                }
            }
            else{
                if ([cell.txtRegister.placeholder isEqualToString:@"City"]) {
                    if (self.strSelectedCity) {
                        cell.txtRegister.text = self.strSelectedCity;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        [cell configureCell:registerModel];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: SO you set a value depending if the cell is nil ? TableViews recycle cells so after the 'first batch' i.e. what you can a see on screen at first load a cell will never be nil again ...

Comment: show `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.....

Comment: Please have a look at the code

Comment: You did not copy the entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method...

Comment: Assign diff. values for "cellIdentifierCell" for each cell. This might work

Comment: this link solve ur problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/uitableviewcells-with-uibutton-overlaps-while-scrolling/22863122#22863122

Comment: cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell]; If there is no reusable cell, it will create a new cell, so, 'cell' will never be nil.

Comment: This may not be the answer it´s just how i do it... in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i do the following: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }` and after that... i set the values for that **cell** before i _return_ it. As i said, maybe it is not the issue here... it´s just how i do it and maybe it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using following line:

```
            NSString *cellIdentifierCell = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"MTRegisterTableViewCell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];
            cell = (MTRegisterTableViewCell *)[tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCell];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[MTUtility 
setXibWithName:@"MTRegisterTableViewCell"] owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not read you whole code, but it sounds like you'll need to **reset the placeholders before a cell gets reused**, they are not necessarly recreated on scroll, that is the point of a table view after all.

See [**`-[UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse). It is called upon dequeue / reuse an existing table cell, so technically when you call `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` (You'll need to subclass `UITableViewCell`, it organizes your code further anyway).