# Custom UItableViewCell label is overlapping

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

Using `UITableView` and found that `cells` are not dequeuing properly.I have created prototype cells using `storyboard`,and have `UIlabel` over cell.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
     UILabel*textLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyUnderwood" size:16];
    textLabel.text = [_tableLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;


}
```

Here is the image of `UITableView` which i am getting when i scroll the `TableView`

[image]

Comment: Is this you're real code ? Because textLabel is not used and it does not make much sense. It doesn't seem wrong neither. Do you have a uilabel in your custom cell ?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/uitableviewcells-with-uibutton-overlaps-while-scrolling/22863122#22863122

Comment: Do you by chance have multipe UILabels with the same tag in the prototype cell?

Comment: @Justafinger Yes i have UILabel in my custom cell.

Comment: That would be great to have your real/full code for that method.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have used that code ,removing all uiview's before  creating cell but it is not drawing properly .some text appear after scroll and the background of cell also disappears

Comment: try this UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

Comment: @akashg It solved when i used different tag ..Thanks..I wasted a day in such a minor mistake.

Comment: @SahebSingh It happens to the best of us. Have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could simply be a minor mistake. Try using a different tag value, or verify the values being used in the prototype cell.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your custom cell in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. Code looks fine just inseatd of `UITableViewCell` dequeue your custom cell like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell"; //needs to be the identifier you defined in story boards
    YourCustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[YourCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
     UILabel*textLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyUnderwood" size:16];
    textLabel.text = [_tableLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;


}
```

Then you need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell and name it YourCustomCell and link all `IBOutlet` objects like labels etc.  put this line of code on top of your .h file `#import YourCustomCell.h` and simply access all properties of that cell like `cell.textLabel` instead of createting label and casting it to view with tag.

Comment: how do you know that "cell" is not the identifier for his custom cell ?

Comment: Because cell he initializes is of type UITableViewCell. This really might be a problem

Comment: Every custom cell inherits from UITableViewCell so this should pose as a problem only if he tries to access a custom property for the custom cell which doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: instead of creating custom cell i have used `prototypeCell` and instead of creating outlets i have used tags to represent every element. So whats the difference?

Comment: The difference is you have a customTableview cell created in storyboards. This cell is presented in your tableView and casted to `UITableViewCell` which makes the overlapping of your labels. Having custom cell in story boards you will more than likely have to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and do all the customization there

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using "nil" instead of cellIdentifier

eg:
   Instead of

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Use this

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

It did  the trick for me

Comment: it is giving me error. `'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: make sure you return your cell you have put nil in the identifier not in the return statement

Answer (score -1):

You just need to tick the "clears graphic context" property of the label in storyboard.