# Custom cell in UITableView make images overlap on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created custom table view cell that have 2 images on it (initially set to be hidden).
When I render each cell I check some status and set images visible/hidden property.
When I open that table it looks fine when I scroll to the bottom and back to the top first 2-3 cells have both image displayed.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";{
OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
...
cell.Title.text = @"some value";
...
if(...){
cell.image1.hidden = YES;
cell.image2.hidden = NO;
}
else{
cell.image1.hidden = NO;
cell.image2.hidden = YES;
}
...
```

Why this could happen?
Is the problem maybe with `CellIdentifier`.

**UPDATE**

First try:

```
OrderCustomCell *cell; 

    if(cell == nil){

        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    }
```

Second try:

```
OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){

        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    }
```

Comment: use this this is working fine for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/uitableviewcells-with-uibutton-overlaps-while-scrolling/22863122#22863122

Comment: If I set Identifier to nil app crash. And if add `for(UIView *view in...` nothing happens.

Comment: if u don't mine, can u update the ?, plz

Comment: change  this only OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

Comment: Again crash. `must pass a valid reuse identifier to UITableView`

Comment: Just look into your condition to hide or show image. That would be the spot which would be creating issue. Also is it boolean and how you setting that check value for showing or hiding image.

Comment: Are you using storyboard or nibs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";
OrderCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if(cell == nil){
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
...
cell.Title.text = @"some value";
 ...
if(...){
cell.image1.hidden = YES;
cell.image2.hidden = NO;
}
else{
cell.image1.hidden = NO;
cell.image2.hidden = YES;
}
...
```

Comment: Still the same images overlaps after scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an identifier.

```
NSString *identifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. I had same issue, fixed now.

Comment: crash couldn't be because of above code. There would be some other reason of crash. Please update reason. This is working fine with me.

Comment: are you sure your crash is not because of Custom Cell 'OrderCustomCell' as in NibWithNibName you are using 'myCustomCell'. Please double check this thing also.

Comment: My custom cell nib name is `myCustomCell` I also use the same name for identifier in nib `myCustomCell` I tried to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, it works for me.

```
            OrderCustomCell * orderCustomCell = (OrderCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

            if (orderCustomCell==nil) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                orderCustomCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
```

Comment: never overlap, i'm sure :))