# Having issue using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier within cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using below code to add a text label into a static table with 4 sections and 3 row in each.
for some reason, when I first run the app its fine, but when I scroll up and down, the UItable doesn't show up properly. Can someone tell why?

```
NSString *identifer = @"net";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer] ;

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifer];


    UILabel *Net= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 220.0, 15.0)];
    Net.tag = indexPath.row;


    Net.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    Net.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
    Net.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    [cell addSubview:Net];

}else {

UILabel *Label1 =(UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    Label1.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    Label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
}

return cell;
```

Comment: When you are using indexPath.row you need to be careful as its value will be zero for some row and there are many views on a row with zero tag value. So you can add some specific value in tag like "tag = 100+indexPath.row"

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/uitableviewcells-with-uibutton-overlaps-while-scrolling/22863122#22863122

Comment: Create a custom cell, don't use the `tag`

Comment: Define "doesn't show up properly".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need and **else** statement while building your cell, this is an edited code that may work out for you:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifer = @"net";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer] ;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifer];

        UILabel *Net= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 220.0, 15.0)];
       // Net.tag = indexPath.row;

        Net.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

        Net.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
        Net.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

        [cell addSubview:Net];

    }
    /*else {

        UILabel *Label1 =(UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
        Label1.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell nr. %d",indexPath.row];
        Label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    }
    */

    return cell;
}
```

I've commented your last lines of code so you won't lose them. If you also set the style of your TabelView as "Grouped", the result you'll get is the following:

http://s2.postimg.org/820thcmy1/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_26_giu_2014_14_46_41.png

Hope this helps!

Comment: By commenting out those lines of code you will never configure a recycled cell. Try your sample app with 100 rows in the section and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer,
I've commented out the 'else' section, the first time I run it, looks OK however after a few scrolls to up and down first section of table shows like this:
http://s10.postimg.org/d7m7ns1t5/image.png

and the last section:
http://s9.postimg.org/vftfggknz/image.png