# How to ressolve iOS UITableView Override UILabel and UITextField on Scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

In my app i have uitableview which has mutiple uitexfiled and uiLabel added as subview.
But when i scroll the UItableView it overirde the uilabel text and uitexfiled text......

Folloiwing is my code:->

```
.h file

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_name;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_address1;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_address2;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_city;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_state;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_zip;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_country;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_telephone;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_website;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_type;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_notes;


@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_contacts;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_projects;

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *lblCompany_activities;




@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_name;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_address1;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_address2;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_city;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_state;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_zip;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_country;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_telephone;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_website;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField *txtCompany_type;




in .m File

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

return 4;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

int num = 0;

 switch (section) 
{

case 0:

num = 9;

break;

case 1:

 num = 2;

break;

case 2:

 num = 2;

break;

case 3:

num = 3;

break;

default:

break;

}

return num;

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]

initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if ([indexPath section]==0)

{

if ([indexPath row]==0)

{

lblCompany_name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

lblCompany_name.tag = 1;


[lblCompany_name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[lblCompany_name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_name setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_name];


txtCompany_name = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_name.placeholder=@"Name";

[txtCompany_name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_name setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_name];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==1)

{

lblCompany_address1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_address1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_address1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_address1 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_address1];


txtCompany_address1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_address1.placeholder=@"address1";

[txtCompany_address1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_address1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_address1];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==2)

{

lblCompany_address2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_address2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_address2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_address2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_address2];


txtCompany_address2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_address2.placeholder=@"address2";

[txtCompany_address2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_address2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_address2];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==3)

{

lblCompany_city = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_city setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_city setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_city setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_city];


txtCompany_city = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_city.placeholder=@"address3";

[txtCompany_city setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_city setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_city];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==4)

{

lblCompany_state = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_state setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_state setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_state setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_state];


txtCompany_state = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_state.placeholder=@"address4";

[txtCompany_state setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_state setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_state];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==5)

{

UIPickerView *statePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 400,216)];

[statePicker setHidden:YES];

[statePicker setDelegate:self];

[statePicker setDataSource:self];

[statePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[statePicker setTag:indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView addSubview:statePicker];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==6)

{

lblCompany_zip = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_zip setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_zip setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_zip setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_zip];


txtCompany_zip = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_zip.placeholder=@"address5";

[txtCompany_zip setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_zip setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_zip];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==7)

{

lblCompany_country = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_country setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_country setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_country setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_country];


txtCompany_country = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_country.placeholder=@"address6";

[txtCompany_country setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_country setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_country];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==8)

{

UIPickerView *countryPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 400, 

216)];

[countryPicker setHidden:YES];

[countryPicker setDelegate:self];

[countryPicker setDataSource:self];

[countryPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[countryPicker setTag:indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView addSubview:countryPicker];


}

}

else if ([indexPath section]==1)

{

if ([indexPath row]==0)

{

lblCompany_telephone = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_telephone setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_telephone setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_telephone setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_telephone];


txtCompany_telephone = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_telephone.placeholder=@"address7";

[txtCompany_telephone setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_telephone setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_telephone];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==1)

{

lblCompany_website = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_website setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_website setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_website setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_website];


txtCompany_website = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_website.placeholder=@"address8";

[txtCompany_website setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_website setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_website];           

}


}

else if ([indexPath section]==2)

 {

 if ([indexPath row]==0)

{

lblCompany_type = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_type setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_type setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_type setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_type];


txtCompany_type = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)];

txtCompany_type.placeholder=@"address9";

[txtCompany_type setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[txtCompany_type setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[cell addSubview:txtCompany_type];



}

else if ([indexPath row]==1)

{

lblCompany_notes = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_notes setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_notes setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_notes setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_notes];

}

}

else if ([indexPath section]==3)

{

if ([indexPath row]==0) 
{

lblCompany_contacts = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_contacts setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_contacts setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_contacts setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_contacts];


UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_plus_sign.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 4, 30, 30)];

cell.accessoryView = btn;

[cell addSubview:btn];


}

else if ([indexPath row]==1)

{

lblCompany_projects = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_projects setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_projects setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_projects setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_projects];



UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_plus_sign.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 4, 30, 30)];

cell.accessoryView = btn;

[cell addSubview:btn];

}

else if ([indexPath row]==2)

{

lblCompany_activities = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];

[lblCompany_activities setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[lblCompany_activities setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[lblCompany_activities setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

[cell addSubview:lblCompany_activities];


UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_plus_sign.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 4, 30, 30)];

cell.accessoryView = btn;

[cell addSubview:btn];


}


}



}


return cell;
}
```

UILabel and UITextFiled text is override when i scroll the UITableView.?

I am not abe to set the text on uiLabel?

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: try this this is useful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/uitableviewcells-with-uibutton-overlaps-while-scrolling/22863122#22863122

Comment: lblCompany_telephone = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 140)];
txtCompany_telephone = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 400, 40)]; you have changed `X Position` now also try to change its `Y Position` as well. Set Different `Y Position` on both

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/22862938/… BY using this link
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

Is it ok if set dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil?

 I have resolve the override issue.....but i am not able to set the Text on uilabel or on uitextfield:

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have write down a IF condition

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Please remove this condition from here ...

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
}
```

Remove this It will work fine

Comment: Yes I read only label & Buttons over ride ... For this It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Unlike UIScrollview `UITableView` isn't capable of having the references of views added to it. You might have **n** number of UITableView But only limited number of tableviewCells are allocated and remaining cells will be reused. So in order to get desired output your **allocation part and subviewing part** can go into if condition setting property part and modifying property should go out of condition . for eg.

```
    if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[Cell alloc]init];
    label = [[MYlabel alloc]init];
    [cell.contentView addSubView:label]
    }
label.text = @"HI";
```

This is the proper way of doing.